# Css of section and small tags are different in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have this html to display a list of people, it contains name and status.

```
<section class="box-time">
    <ul class="group">
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="../loadFancybox.php">
                <span class="info">
                    <strong>Name</strong>
                    <small>
                        <p id="pStatus" class="colorRed">Pending</p>
                    </small>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Here's a CSS that I'm using

```
ul.group li {
    border: 1px transparent solid;
    float: left;        /*  added  */
    min-width: 232px;   /*  added  */
}

section.box-time li:hover{

    background-color:#9495A8
}

section.box-time li a{
    margin:0 10px;
    padding:15px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    color:#444;

}
section.box-time span.info{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:185px;
    max-height:45px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space:normal
}

section.box-time span.info small {

    font:11px/1em Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

section.box-time span.info small p.colorRed{
    color:red;
}

section.box-time span.info small p.colorBlue{
    color:blue;
}

section.box-time span.info small p.colorGreen{
    color:green;
}
```

The problem is they're different in IE (what a surprise, right?).

Here's how it's being displayed in chrome
[image: in Chrome]

Here's how it's being displayed in IE
[image: in IE]

I have also created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/083krhau/

What I need to change to make this html looks the same in both browsers?

Comment: Looks the same for me. Using IE 11 and chrome latest.

Comment: Did you open fiddle? In fiddle they are the same, but I guess It's fiddle rendering correctly. In my application they are all blue as in the picture

Comment: Yes, I opened the fiddle. Do you have your application on a server for we can view it?

Comment: it's taken the default colors for <a> elements and list style (the bullet). looks like for whatever reason ie is NOT taken your css styles but as in the fiddle it looks the same we may need more data to know why

Comment: I just fund out that the problem is that IE is placing <ul></ul> outside the tag section, but I dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming you are using an older version of IE, that was for me the way I could replicate the problem. Older versions do not support html5. you could include this in the head of your website:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('header');
        document.createElement('nav');
        document.createElement('section');
        document.createElement('article');
        document.createElement('aside');
        document.createElement('footer');
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

This will tell them that those tag are html tags as well. 
It is best to remove the tags you don't use

Another solution would be to replace the section with div